# Lombok Not Running in IntelliJ

Tags: java, annotations, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I downloaded a project from my companies source repo. In this project there are lines such as the following:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @_(@Inject))
```

Given the language level this does not compile as _ is a reserved keyword. What is (apparently) supposed to happen is that, as a precompilation step, lombok replaces the underscore. However this does not occur.

I am using IntelliJ 2022.3.1 which comes with lombok preinstalled and it doesn't seem as if uninstalling and reinstalling is an option. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what are SDK and language level? (Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Project)

Comment: I've tried several. At this point, it openjdk-19 using language level 9. I have tried language  level 7,8,9 and 19. I have also tried corretto-18

Answer (score 0):

Consider downgrading SDK and language level to Java 1.8

> Use of '_' as an identifier is not supported in releases since Java 9

also worth checking that annotation processing is enabled

Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors -> Enable annotation processing

[image: enable annotation processing preferences]

Comment: already enabled.

Comment: yup, that is already checked. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I've suggested another action - please check my answer

Comment: when I try downgrading to 1.8 i get the following error:
java: cannot run program "/<path>/pid.7656.temp.jbr/bin/java in directory... error=0, Failed to spawn helper: pid: 2068, exit value: 1 "

Comment: Which OS? Which exactly SDK are you using? Please verify correctness of installation of SDK by compiling/running sample project.
Error appear during build or run of application? if it's the latter try maybe run it in docker container